# Can't locate path: <0>

Tags: php, laravel, plugins

I'm publishing files in my Laravel Plugin, and in this line:

```
    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../config/tournaments.php' => config_path('tournaments.php'), '']);
```

I get :

```
Can't locate path: <0>
```

It is weird because when I print config_path('tournaments.php'), it is OK, and beside, file is well copied.... So, everything works, but I would like to get rid of this message that should not be there....

Any idea????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the empty `''` in the `publishes` array:

```
    $this->publishes([__DIR__ . '/../config/tournaments.php' => config_path('tournaments.php'),]);
```

Laravel succeeds in publishing the `tournaments.php`, but gives you the error for the blank value. Some more info here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/packages#resources